# Robert was a wise man, can you solve his riddle?

Tags: rebus

Can you decipher the musical instruments represented below?

1. P O
2. BA BA
3. ECLART
4. @ # $ %

Unfortunately this isn't one of my original creations. I will provide a link to where I found it from **after** the riddle has been solved to avoid spoilers.

**EXTRA**:

> Just a small question that isn't a part of the riddle, can you find out what's special about this question? 
>   You know me, I cannot be satisfied with just a single layer riddle :P

But don't worry, the extra bit isn't important, just a small bonus for those who enjoy it.

Comment: https://www.braingle.com/brainteasers/teaser.php?op=2&id=11604&comm=0

Taken from here

Comment: Nobody's gonna try to get the hidden riddle here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

P O is a

> Piano (p and o sounds like piano)

BA BA

> Is a Tuba (two ba)

ECLART

> is a Clarinet (Clar in et)

And @#$%

> Are cymbals! (Symbols)

Comment: Nice! A bit too easy was it?